# python threading confusing code 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

its messy i know, but the threading is so confusing ...i dont know if the problem is in my sintax or if it is in the method im using...
the def do inserts in mysql (and its working when is not threading),another strange thing is that after runing the code i noticed rows are inserted correctly but i still get "self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

```
def thistaginsert(tagy):
    global idn
    global forbidentags
    global termcount
    tagy = tagy[0]
    if not tagy.isdigit():
        if not tagy in forbidentags:
            wordpress.execute(s_term % tagy)
            term0 = wordpress.fetchall()
            term0 = term0[0][0]
            if term0 == 0:
                tmp_i_term = i_term.format(tag1=tagy, tag2=tagy)
                wordpress.execute(tmp_i_term)
                cnx2.commit()
                tmp_s_termname = s_termname.format(buceta=tagy)
                wordpress.execute(tmp_s_termname)
                term = wordpress.fetchall()
                term = term[0]
                wordpress.execute(i_termtax % term)
                cnx2.commit()
                wordpress.execute(s_tax % term)
                tax_id = wordpress.fetchall()
                tax_id = tax_id[0][0]
                tmp_i_RL = i_RL.format(idn=idn, taxid=tax_id)
                wordpress.execute(tmp_i_RL)
                cnx2.commit()
                termcount += 1
            else:
                tmp_s_termname = s_termname.format(buceta=tagy)
                wordpress.execute(tmp_s_termname)
                term = wordpress.fetchall()
                term = term[0]
                wordpress.execute(s_tax % term)
                tax_id = wordpress.fetchall()
                tax_id = tax_id[0][0]
                tmp_i_RL = i_RL.format(idn=idn, taxid=tax_id)
                wordpress.execute(tmp_i_RL)
                cnx2.commit()
                termcount += 1
        return termcount
.
.
. #many lines later
                if tags:
                  for tag in tags:
                        ttt = Thread(target=thistaginsert(tag))
                        ttt.start()
                        threads.append(ttt)
                else:
                    print('no tags')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are directly calling the function and then passing the result to the `Thread()` constructor as the target function.  Since the function returns an int, that explains the error; you are trying to use an int as the thread's entry point, and an int is not callable.

Presumably you intended to have the function invocation happen on another thread.  To make that happen, change this:

```
ttt = Thread(target=thistaginsert(tag))
#                   ^
# This invokes the function and uses the result as the "target" argument.
```

To:

```
ttt = Thread(target=lambda: thistaginsert(tag))
#                   ^
# This syntax creates a new function object that will call thistaginsert(tag) when
# it is called, and that new function is what gets passed as the "target" argument.
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you can also do this:

```
ttt = Thread(target=thistaginsert, args=(tag,))
#                               ^ Note the lack of parens; we are passing the
#                                 function object, not calling it!
```

Comment: Don't wrap it in a `lambda`, just pass `target=thistaginsert, args=(tag,)`.

Comment: @abarnert That is another approach. Personally I find this more readable, but I will add yours as an alternative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the core devs expect `args` to be the one obvious way to do it, or they wouldn't have bothered adding it in the first place…

Comment: @abarnert I'm not at all saying it doesn't work, and we could argue about it for a while probably. I just find the `args` keyword argument redundant in a language that has closures.

Comment: @cdhowie "mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found." this means i cant thread a select? the threading is using the same cursor

Comment: @cdhowie: It's not a matter of "works" or "doesn't work", it's a matter of "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @user3610512 It is unlikely that using the same cursor from multiple threads is allowed. Using different cursors may be allowed depending on the driver.

Comment: @abarnert I can buy that, but then the most obvious way that would work everywhere would be no `args` keyword, and using lambdas -- otherwise we are just providing another mechanism alongside of closures. :) I consider this an API defect in this Python module.

Comment: @user3610512: See [`threadsafety`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety) in PEP 249 (the DB-API 2.0 spec). Most database modules provide level 1 or 2, not 3, but instead of relying on "most database modules", the best thing to do is `import whatever; print(whatever.threadsafety)` and see what it says.