# object is not callable while using threading?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple function that checks whether a folder has a single .txt file in it every 5 seconds. I am using threading to run the function every 5 seconds. When the function is to be called a second time i get an error "*'bool' object is not callable*". I am not sure what I dm doing wrong. It was able to run the first time

program code

```
import threading

import glob

DIR = r'C:\test_folder\dl_file'

def download_wait5(path_to_downloads):
    dl_wait2 = True
    dlCounter = len(glob.glob1(path_to_downloads,"*.txt"))
    if dlCounter == 1:
        dl_wait2 = True
        print("True")
    else:
        dl_wait2 = False
        print("False")
    return dl_wait2

t = threading.Timer(5.0, download_wait5(DIR))
t.start()
```

Output

```
True

Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 1166, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I am not sure wha t I am doing wrong. All I want the function to do is return **True** or **False** depending if the folder has a .txt file or not.

I also tried this code below after reading the correct syntax for Threading https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html but this time it only runs once and then stops:

```
t = threading.Timer(1.0, download_wait5, args=[DIR])
t.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python threading confusing code 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734595/python-threading-confusing-code-int-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `download_wait5()` immediately and passing **its return value** to the thread. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: HI Thank you for your help. I changed my script based on what I read on syntax for Threading https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html.     <br/>However the script now runs once and then stops where it should run every second and print("True") as i have 1 sample .txt file in the folder.   <br/>


    `t = threading.Timer(1.0, download_wait5, args=[DIR])`

    `t.start()`